# Injecting a Java class into Grails Groovy service

Tags: grails, groovy

It is very easy to inject groovy services into other groovy services or controllers. However, i can't figure out how to inject a Java class into a groovy service.

Is it possible to perform such dependency injection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. All you have to do is to define your bean in `resources.groovy` like e.g.

```
beans = {
    //....
    myJavaComponent(com.example.YourJavaComponent) {
        //if it has any external dependencies you can define them as follow:
        externalDependency = ref('idOfTheBeanToInject')
}
```

Then all you have to do is just simply inject this bean into your Grails service by defining a property in class: `def myJavaComponent`, that's all.

See [*Using the Spring Bean DSL* in the Grails docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/spring.html#springdslAdditional)

Comment: What is idOfTheBeanToInject? and should myJavaComponent be the name of the class?

Comment: `myJavaComponent` is the name (identifier) of your bean in Spring beans container. The simplest convention is to name your bean using your class simple name starting with lower case, eg. if your class name is `MyJavaComponent` your bean's identifier could be `myJavaComponent`. `idOfTheBeanToInject` is the name (identifier) of other bean you would like to inject - if your Java class don't have any properties that use injected beans, you can simple skip this line `internalDependency = ref('idOfTheBeanToInject')`